# Invoke-WmiMethod not working with powershell pssession (invoke-command)

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am simply trying to execute a program on a remote machine using a pssession:

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {cd c:\
powershell; Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -name create -argumentlist $arra
y}

My array of arguments looks like this:

```
$array
c:\powershell\sqbconverter.exe
d:\Restore\xxxx\FULL_(local)_xxxx_PROD_20131016_230001.sqb
D:\Restore\xxxx\full\Restore_xxxx_full.bak
xxxxxx
```

This is the result:

```
PSComputerName     : hostname1
RunspaceId         : 92656a18-ca0f-4684-aff2-086f109fce59
PSShowComputerName : True
__GENUS            : 2
__CLASS            : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS       :
__DYNASTY          : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH          :
__PROPERTY_COUNT   : 2
__DERIVATION       : {}
__SERVER           :
__NAMESPACE        :
__PATH             :
ProcessId          :
ReturnValue        : 21
```

I'm not sure how to debug what exactly is happening on the remote machine but I am not getting my desired output (*the exe should create an output file*). Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you running `Invoke-WmiMethod` via `Invoke-Command -Session` instead of running it directly against the remote host (`Invoke-WmiMethod -Computer ...`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your `$array` into the scripblock you pass to `Invoke-Command` e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($arr)
    cd c:\ powershell
    Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_Process -Name create -ArgumentList $arr} -Arg $array
```